# How secure is Cognito?

Tags: cognito-forms

Adobe Forms Central had a decent level of security. I've been told some software providers state in T&C's that they own the data you submit!

What's the score with Cognito?

Is submission content encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

These questions were addressed previously in another [Stack Exchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70176/what-measures-does-cognito-forms-take-to-ensure-privacy-security-level-for-comp/70184#70184), please review as I believe it covers everything you are asking about.  Thanks.