# Are uploads to Cognito Forms secure or protected?

Tags: cognito-forms

Are (or, how are) files uploaded to Cognito Forms protected?

I have found information regarding the form entries being protected but nothing that explicitly stated that the uploads are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) now supports [full encryption](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/data-encryption) of all entry data **and uploaded files** at rest.  Furthermore, you can mark sensitive fields as protected to ensure they are not inadvertently transmitted insecurely, such as through email notifications or insecure redirects/webhooks.

Learn more about Cognito Forms security at: http://help.cognitoforms.com/data-security

---

Sounds like you have already read this question and answer on the topic:

[What measures does Cognito Forms take to ensure Privacy/ Security Level for Completed Forms/ User Data?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70176/what-measures-does-cognito-forms-take-to-ensure-privacy-security-level-for-comp/70184#70184)

All files are store in Microsoft Azure datacenters, carefully segmented by organization to keep files safe.  All web traffic to/from Cognito Forms is encrypted to ensure the safety of data in transit.  Currently, we do not encrypt these files in Azure, but they do require an authenticated user from the organization in order to access them.

We plan to support full encryption of uploaded files as an option for forms later this year, which will additionally prevent files from being transmitted via email or otherwise sent through unencrypted channels.

Comment: Hi Jamie, that's great. Thanks for your help!