# How secure is information is Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have already read through your answer discussing the securities in November 2014. Are there not any updates since then? and if we would prefer to call Cognito and discuss this in detail over the phone where can I find a phone number? 
We were previously using Adobe Forms Central for client Questionnaires. These forms are for our estate planning law firm and so the data put into the forms by our clients ABSOLUTELY needs to be secure. Can someone please give me a complete explanation of the securities, not just a generic answer? We really love your forms here but will not be able to use them if our clients information is exposed in any way. Thank you

Comment: Since this question has changed significantly since asked, I should clarify that the security of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) is, to the best of my knowledge, more secure than Adobe FormsCentral.  We have a HIPAA BAA with Microsoft and our servers and data are given extra protections by Microsoft.  We plan to add HIPAA-level security later this year, which will allow us to provide BAA's to our customers as well, but this requires that we take further steps to prevent our customers from accidentally transmitting sensitive data, like sending an email notification with PHI.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) now supports [full encryption](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/data-encryption) of all entry data and uploaded files at rest.  Furthermore, you can mark sensitive fields as protected to ensure they are not inadvertently transmitted insecurely, such as through email notifications or insecure redirects/webhooks.

Learn more about Cognito Forms security at: https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/74/entries/data-security

---

Please see the following question/answer, which answers your question regarding the security of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in detail:

[What measures does Cognito Forms take to ensure Privacy/ Security Level for Completed Forms/ User Data?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70176/what-measures-does-cognito-forms-take-to-ensure-privacy-security-level-for-comp)

Comment: So there have been no updates since November 2014? Why can I not find a phone number to call someone at Cognito forms to discuss the securities in more detail?

Comment: Correct, our security measures are the same then as today.  Microsoft has beefed up their security measures since then even further, and links to these are included in our response.  We have customers in all 24 time-zones and are located on the US East Coast, so we offer email support to our customers.  Please use the Write Us option on our home page to reach out to us and we'll be glad to give you a call.

Comment: We have now released support for encryption "at rest" for all entry data and uploaded files.  Additionally you can now prevent accidental data loss by protecting fields, which prevents them from being transmitted insecurely via email notifications and/or redirects/webwooks.